# Fuelphp Class 'OAuth\Fuel' not found error

Tags: php, oauth, fuelphp

I've been trying to set up ninjauth but see to have run into a problem for some reason fuel doesn't seem to be recognizing the oauth package correctly and I am getting the following error

```
ErrorException [ Error ]: Class 'OAuth\Fuel' not found
PKGPATH/oauth/classes/request.php @ line 477
```

I have made sure the package is installed in /fuel/packages/oauth
added it to the config file in /fuel/app/config/config.php so it looks like

```
'packages' => array(
'orm','ninjauth','oauth','oauth2','auth'
),
```

and ran a migration on it

```
php oil refine migrate --packages=oauth
```

I am developing locally on OSX(10.5.8) using MAMP as my server if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was a namespace issue and has been fixed in this commit

https://github.com/fuel-packages/fuel-oauth/commit/57da924ffcd1f9d08fe3f2d40e4b35b0a92d8c94

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble and it turns out I did not have cURL as part of my php installation.
I corrected the issue on Linux by running: sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl